# Reading set of lines from a file

Tags: files, scripting

I have a file of 1000 lines. I need to read that file 10/20 lines per time and execute those or save it into other file. Next time it should read the file from 11/21 and do the same.This should be done till the EOF.

How should I restrict the number while reading from file?

Comment: How are you reading the file? Is this in a shell script?

Comment: yes, using shell script.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us how you are reading the file. Normally, you read one line at a time. What are you trying to achieve by reading 10 lines at once?

Comment: After executing the first bunch of lines, what triggers execution of the next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplistically:

```
while read -r one
do 
  read -r two && 
  read -r three && 
  read -r four && 
  read -r five && 
  read -r six && 
  read -r seven && 
  read -r eight && 
  read -r nine && 
  read -r ten && 
  printf "%s\n" "$one" "$two" "$three" "$four" "$five" "$six" "$seven" "$eight" "$nine" "$ten"
  ## or whatever you want to do to process those lines
  echo END OF SECTION 
done < input-file
```

This could "easily" enough be extended to read twenty lines at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
while read line1 && [do something with $line1]
do
    read line2 && [do something with $line2]
    read line3 && [do something with $line3]
    […]
done < file.txt
```

However, it is very strange to have the restriction on reading exactly N lines, unless your data structure is a fixed number of lines. Usually what is attempted by reading several lines at a time is some sort of parallelism, which would be better achieved by using either `xargs` (to handle multiple `$lineN` variables in a single command), `parallel` (to use a worker model to handle lines ASAP), or a combination of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, to read 5 lines:

```
N=5; # Number of lines to process together (YMMV)
cat input_file |
while IFS= read -r v1; do
   eof=
   for i in $(seq 2 "$N"); do
      IFS= read -r "v$i" || { unset -v eof; break; }
   done
   ${eof+:} break
   echo "The 5 lines read in are: $v1 $v2 $v3 $v4 $v5"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `split` and filter the file...

```
split -l 20 --filter='command'  input_file
```

Example: split in chunks of 20 lines and choose one random line from each chunk (`shuf -n 1`)

```
split -l 20 --filter='shuf -n 1' input_file
```

The sama command (split) may be used to create a file for each chunk:

```
split -l 20 input-file input-file-chunk-
```

creating `input-file-chunk-aa` `nput-file-chunk-ab` etc